# String literals and multiple versions of a template function

Tags: c++, c++11

Let’s say I have a templated function:

```
template<typename... Args>
void my_log_function(Args&&... args)
{
    // Work, work, work.
}
```

And then invoke it as:

```
my_log_function("1");
my_log_function("22");
my_log_function("333");
my_log_function("4444");
my_log_function("55555");
```

Since the type of a string literal is `const char[n]`, I believe this will create a lot of instantiations of `my_log_function` (Visual Studio Intellisense seems to suggest this). Has anyone observed this as a problem? Can it be? Can it be prevented?

Comment: `my_log_function(+"1")` deduces `Args...` to be `const char*` (using unary `+`); similarly you could dispatch the work to another template, passing decayed arguments (with the intent of eliminating / inlining the originally invoked function)

Comment: DyP: Nice trick! But I think it would leave many people baffled...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this should create a different instance of class template. They should only differ in the size of the array passed by reference and if they array isn't really used any further as array, the generated code should be identical. As far as I know, VC++ folds identical code. If the type is propagated a lot, it may yield code bloat, however.

One way to prevent the code bloat is to conditionally decay types and forward to another template doing the actual work. I *think* this should do the trick:

```
template <typename... Args>
void my_real_log_function(Args&&... args) {
    // real implementation goes here
}

template <typename T>
struct decay_array {
    typedef typename std::condition<
        std::is_array<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::value,
        typename std::decay<T>::type,
        T>::type type;
};

template <typename... Args>
void my_log_function(Args&&... args) {
    my_real_log_function(std::forward<typename std::decay_array<Args>::type>(args)...);
}
```

The original version just using `typename std::decay<T>::type` doesn't work because it would turn references to non-arrays into values which isn't intended.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: If some of the arguments are large and/or non-copyable arguments, passing them by values my not be intended.

Comment: @DyP: yes, you are right: `std::decay` is too aggressive and removes references, too. Seems, it should only decay when passing in references to arrays making the delegation a bit more interesting.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: agreed. I didn't claim it does work. ... and I changed the code to only use `std::decay` when the argument is an array - I think. Something turning arrays into pointers and then delegating to another function is, however, the general approach. Since this is likely to be a common need it may be worth to investigate how to make this operation easy.

Comment: OK… the new code has unbalanced angle brackets and `condition` instead of `conditional`…

Comment: `typename std::remove_reference<T>::value` should probably be `typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::value` to balance the brackets

Comment: @DyP: yes. The code wasn't (possibly isn't) ready for copy&paste but should still display the overall idea... (I added the missing `::type>`

Answer (score 1):

The solution is not to implement "work, work, work" in such a function. Sanitize the variable arguments into something more canonical and hand the work to a non-template.

Mind the bloat and remember that the template system is designed to generate inline functions.